# Change extJS ButtonPanel alignment using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, extjs

I see the following piece of code in a vendor software (when I view source). It seems this information is hard-coded somewhere and there is no easy way to change the Alignment.

However I do have access to add Javascript at the header/footer of the page. What script I need to add to correctly reference the rendered ButtonPanel and change the alignment to left from right.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Ext.onReady(function(){
    var buttonPanel = new Ext.Panel({
        renderTo: 'imbuttonpanel_0',
        border: false,
        buttonAlign: 'right',
        unstyled: true,
        fbar: {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            hideBorders: true,
            items: [
    {
        id: 'action.standardsearch.select',
        text: 'Select',
        handler: function(){imSubmitAction('action.standardsearch.select', '1', false);}
    }
,
    {
        id: 'action.standardsearch.cancel',
        text: 'Cancel',
        cls: 'ca-gray',     handler: function(){imSubmitAction('action.standardsearch.cancel', '1', false);}
    }

            ]
        }
    });
 } );
</script>
```

---

I have zero extJS skills and I added the following block (which follows right after) w/o success:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Ext.onReady(function(){
        buttonPanel.buttonAlign = 'left';
 } );
</script>
```

I see the following error in the Debugger:

Error: ReferenceError: buttonPanel is not defined

Thanks for your help and time.

---

Edit 2:
Vendor confirmed the above code is in a Jar file. They further stated and w/o my asking that it might be possible to reference the element using JS and change alignment.

On further examination of the code, I found the following DIV element right above the above JS code which the buttonPanel is rendering to using the "renderTo: 'imbuttonpanel_0'" property. But again, the DIV element does not use any CSS and it also seems to be hard-coded in the source code as well. Below is the DIV exactly as seen in View Source.

```
<div id="imbuttonpanel_0">


</div>
```

So I got excited about it that I should be able to reference the DIV element using JS and change alignment of the DIV itself which may force the buttonPanel to the left. But sadly it did not work either. I added the following JS line to the footer (thru a GUI interface):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("imbuttonpanel_0").setAttribute('align', 'left');
    //document.getElementById("imbuttonpanel_0").style.marginLeft = "50px";
</script>
```

---

Edit 3: Reason for trying to change the default behavior: Search page displays a table of results with quite a few columns. The Select Radio/Check box for each record is on the very left. And the Select / Cancel buttons are to the extreme right and on smaller screens / lower resolutions, the Users have to scroll right to get to the Select button.

Answer (score 0):

Because `buttonPanel` is a `var` within a function, it is not accessible to any code outside of that function. However, since the effect of the JS is to generate HTML and CSS, you should be able to find the corresponding HTML/CSS and change the alignment styling after it has been emitted.

So the essence of your `onReady()` function should be to locate and alter the HTML/CSS, not attempt to change the JavaScript object.

As something of an aside, contrary to @Hayk (whose "answer" should be a comment), I don't see how this is somehow a fundamentally incorrect thing to want to do, especially in a situation where you don't have control of the existing source which is setting the alignment to begin with.

Comment: Aah, thanks for clarifying on the var being inside the extJS function. Did not realize that. Last night I tried something similar to what you are suggesting and have updated my original post. Can you please take a look at it and comment. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It looks like you are now trying to change the HTML element's `align` attribute; I think you should rather be altering the associated style identified by `imbuttonpanel_0`, or overriding the style on the element itself - something like `...style.textAlign="left"`.

Comment: I have searched (full text search folders/sub-folders) the length and breadth of the files available to view (which not packaged in war/jar files), there are many .css files but there is no entry for imbuttonpanel_0 in any of them or the included css when viewed source.

Comment: ...also when viewed source on the page itself, there is no other reference to imbuttonpanel_0 then already mentioned in my post. So you have the Div element and its reference in the ExtJS onReady function. Thats it.